# Finally installed MySQL for Rails in Windows 64 bit, and now

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Environment:

```
Windows 7 64bit (Home Premium)

Ruby 1.9.2 p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

Rails 3.0.10

MySQL 5.5
```

Ruby, despite my having successfully installed the `mysql2` rubygem thinks that the gem is missing when I invoke a rails command that requires it.

After having spent the evening getting the mysql rubygem installed on Windows 64 bit, I decided to (finally) get cracking on linking mysql to a local rails server. This is how I was trying to do it...

(Fairly) Exact transcript from `cmd.exe`

```
C:\rails\cookbook>gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=c:\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=c:\mysql\lib
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
(I thought this was successful mysql install, should I test it somehow?)

C:\>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=c:\mysql\include --with-mysql-lib=c:\mysql\lib
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.7.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.7...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.7...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
(Same as above - I thought this was successful mysql install)

C:\rails>rails new cookbook -d mysql
(successfully creates directories for project in c:\rails\cookbook)

C:\rails\cookbook>rails server
?[31mCould not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.2.11)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.?[0m
?[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.?[0m
```

Notes:
I noticed it wants rubygem `mysql2-0.2.11`, I have `0.3.7`. I tried installing `0.2.11` specifically by the method I used to install the two gems above. No dice, it couldn't find a gem by the name `mysql2-0.2.11` in 'any repository'

I'm stumped, any thoughts fellas (and gals)?

Comment: Windows isn't the best platform for ruby web development. I suggest making a Linux VM with VirtualBox and Vagrant (http://vagrantup.com/) unless you have a specific need to run on Windows. If your actual deployment environment is Linux it certainly is in your best interest to develop in a Linux VM so your production and dev envs are as close as possible. I don't think you'll run into any of these problems with a Linux box as that's what most developers use and you'll be able to get more access to help.

Comment: @Cixate or at the minimum something like sqlite3 which has much more mature integration with Windows + RoR

Answer (score 2):

I believe your MySQL installation is a 64bits (like Windows), correct?

Ruby is 32bits, so you **cannot link 32bits against 64bits**.

I've posted a article covering the installation steps on my blog:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

These steps use MySQL Connector/C to workaround the 32bits versus 64bits issues.

Both `mysql` or `mysql2` gem should work with this.

Comment: Happy to hear! don't forget to mark the question as resolved so other finds it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `mysql2` in your `Gemfile` and subsequently executed `bundle install` ?

Answer (score 0):

@@ my sql installation (on 64 bit architecture)

## download connector (download zip file and extract it to c drive)

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

## download mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html

## command to install mysql with connector

```
C:\Sites\rails_project\resume>gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-
dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-6.1.0-win32
```

After this copy libmysql.dll from connector folder and paste it to ruby>bin folder